# Script SQL para encontrar os vencedores em site de leilão

Tags: mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um site de leilão em PHP e MySQL e quero exibir o relatório dos vencedores - ou seja, das pessoas que fizeram maiores propostas em diferentes leilões (posts).

Essa é estrutura da entidade que armazena os lances é `comentario(id_com, id_user, id_post, prospota)`. Gostaria de retornar todos que efectuaram a maior proposta de cada leilão.

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCjS7.png)

Comment: Olá @octavio cossa, qual seria a base de dados? MySQL? Qual versão? Está usando algum CMS, como Wordpress? Algum plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que nenhuma proposta pode ser repetida para cada leilão, é possível fazer a seguinte query

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM comentario c1
INNER JOIN (SELECT ci.id_user, MAX(ci.proposta) AS maiorproposta
            FROM comentario ci GROUP BY ci.id_post) c2
  ON (c1.proposta = c2.maiorproposta);
```

Para isso, assumi que é usado MySQL 5 com a seguinte estrutura

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comentario` (
  `id_com` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_post` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `proposta` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_com`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Disponibilizo um SQL Fiddle com a resposta neste [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43ed7f/7/0).

Comment: Obrigado funcionou #tvdias..

Comment: Olá @octaviocossa, bem vindo ao SO em português. Aconselho seguir o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver a melhor forma de agradecer por uma resposta :)

Comment: @octaviocossa, não esqueça de aceitar a resposta, caso lhe tenha sido útil.